# rescue retry Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

Returning to Ruby after a long break, I'm trying to run a rescue retry block with an RSpec assertion with Capybara / Cucumber.  I have the following which is purposely designed to fail to test my retry.  It doesn't appear to be running the retry, I have gotten confused:

```
  begin
    retries ||= 2
    a = 1
    a.eql? 2 # false
    raise
  rescue
    puts 'Retrying assertion for failed step'
    retries -= 1
    if retries > 0
      sleep 0.5 # allows render of screen content
      retry
    end
  end
```

I do suspect I've written something wrong here. Is this the case?

Comment: Could you provice a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), ie an example without rspec involved?

Comment: Edited, is that OK?

Comment: I thought you were asking about the RSpec test. Now after the edit I have no idea what you are asking - the code correctly retries twice then exits.

Comment: edited version works correctly on my machine

Comment: Works for me, Ruby 2.5.5.

Comment: unusually, I wasn't getting the puts in console even though the statement was false.

Answer (score 2):

RSpec works by throwing `RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError` when an `expect` fails. You are catching it with your unlimited `rescue`, so RSpec never sees it, which makes your test pass. Never ever use unlimited `rescue`. Always use a typed rescue, with the most general type being `StandardError` (not `Exception`!) -  but make it as tight and specific as possible.

If you *meant* to catch `ExpectationNotMetError` and retry twice, then let it happen afterwards, you need to reraise it (using plain `raise`) for RSpec to see it, otherwise Ruby considers it to be handled and execution continues normally (and RSpec doesn't see it). You should still rescue it specifically, just to be safe from other possible errors you could do in the rescued block.

---

*) unless you *know* that *exactly one* thing can go wrong (and even then triple-check).